# Cleaning up crazy geometry

Tags: mesh, faces, topology

What is the best way to make this back faces be a single ngon? Is there a way or the only way is the good old manual work?[image]

[image]

Comment: have your tried to boolean? You also have the TinyCAD>XALL

Comment: Yes, i tried boolean, sadly the results were bad. I'll take a look at TInyCad, thank you for your answer!

Comment: TinyCad had no good auto result. It's crazy to think that something like this gotta be manual

Comment: you need to give some corrections with TinyCAD, once you've applied, delete all the inner vertices and merge by distance and you'll get the outer vertices

Comment: The closest I can think of, would be to select the first face. Use the select menu to select co-planer.  That should select all of the other faces.  Delete "Only faces".  That should leave you with all of the necessary vertices selected.  Merge "by distance".  That should leave you with a single outline boundary.  Make a face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest method I've found, which doesn't outwit Booleans, fills, or intersection-finding...

Starting in the flat,  with your collection of edges filled or not, Mesh menu > *Knife Project* them down onto a clean plane..

[image]

.. select external faces, and delete..

[image]

.. then <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* on [all selected] works, and the Ngon can be extruded.